# From Code Editor to Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I recently created a webpage for my using the Codepen online editor. I made it responsive and have everything in place to migrate it to my Wordpress page.

The only problem is I'm not sure how to migrate pure html/css to Wordpress. It seems by it's nature that Wordpress is structured around themes.
What suggestions do you have for migrating the code over so it works in Wordpress?

Also, since most of the coding I do is by hand (not using themes) is Wordpress the best site to use?

Comment: I've removed the link to Codepen from your question, as it's not really relevant. If you feel the code is relevant, please edit your question adding the link back *and* the code copy/pasted from Codepen :)

Answer (score 2):

If that's ALL the site, then there's not much point in using wordpress - just make it static.

If you want to expand it later and think you'll need a CMS's data management tools, with Wordpress you will have to create a theme. But the bare minimum for that is only a `index.php` (put your code there) and a `style.css` (for the stylesheet, obviously).

Just make sure to also add the head markup to your site and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks.  I had no idea there was a difference between a static website and a CMS.  I'm going to go do some more research!

Comment: A CMS (like Wordpress) is basically a database management tool - it will store the content in the database then generate most/all pages on-the-fly, upon request, based on templates. Can't really be done without if you frequently update the site with structured content. But if you only have a couple of pages and they're meant to more-or-less stay that way, using a CMS would become just a useless hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you add a database -- wordpress, joomla or other -- you're slowing things down. If you're expecting to be managing over 50 pages, that's a good trade-off, but if not, you're probably not making use of the best parts of wordpress.

One thing with Codepen: It has a few helpers -- autoprefixer, normalizer, maybe you're using Sass? Built-in helpers. Make sure they are compiled into your final CSS/HTML.